# Error in call to API function "users/get_current_account": Unexpected URL params: "access_token" on Dropbox API

Tags: c#, json, dropbox, win-universal-app, dropbox-api

MainViewModel:

```
 public async Task<string> Httpclient(string link,string oauthToken)
        {    

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", oauthToken);

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(link,new StringContent(""));
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
```

Get_account_ViewModel:

```
public class Get_Current_Account_ViewModel
    {
        MainViewModel mainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
        public async Task<Model.Get_Current_Account.RootObject> get_current_account(string _accessToken)
        {
            var query = await mainViewModel.Httpclient("https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/users/get_current_account?access_token=_accessToken",_accessToken);
            if (query != null)
            {
                var get_data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model.Get_Current_Account.RootObject>(query);
                return get_data;
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
```

I tried on two ways:

- the first way: I got a problem is

**Error in call to API function "users/get_current_account": Unexpected URL params: "access_token" on Dropbox API**

*at*

**var query = await mainViewModel.Httpclient("https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/users/get_current_account?access_token=_accessToken",_accessToken);**

- second way: **Error in call to API function "users/get_current_account": Bad HTTP "Content-Type" header: "text/plain; charset=utf-8".  Expecting one of "application/json", "application/json; charset=utf-8", "text/plain; charset=dropbox-cors-hack".**   when I remove **?access_token=_accessToken** at var query.

Please everyone solve this problem. I can not fix it. thanks.

Comment: Cross-linking with the Dropbox API forum: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/204734063-Error-in-call-to-API-function-users-get-current-account-Unexpected-URL-params-access-token-.

Answer (score 0):

You were right to get rid of the `access_token` parameter, since, as the error says, that's not a valid parameter.

The next error indicates that you're sending the wrong `Content-Type` header, so try sending the right one. E.g.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(
    link, new StringContent("", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

(This code is untested, just reading [the docs on `StringContent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.stringcontent(v=vs.118).aspx).)

Comment: Error in call to API function \"users/get_current_account\": request body: could not decode input as JSON

Comment: Perhaps try passing `"null"`, which is valid JSON.

Comment: Did you try passing `"null"` as I suggested? Though honestly, I think an empty body should be fine. Maybe you can share your current code.

Comment: this code is currentlly. your mean HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(
    link, new StringContent(NULL, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

Comment: I DON'T UNDERSTAND YOUR MIND.